# Skip duplicate for idempotent file2 component

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel over a clustered environment and want to use a readlock on my file consumer endpoint so only one server tries to process each file.
The only cluster safe readlock is the idempotent readlock however this requires an idempotentRepository to be set on the file uri.

I use an idempotent consumer within the route which moves any duplicate files to an error folder and logs the error to a specific file. This uses a specified JDBCMessageIdRepository to store the idempotent keys.

Is there a way to use the duplicate handling logic from the idempotent consumer with the idempotent readlock? Or a way to set the idempotentRepository in the file component to not skip the duplicates so they are picked up by the idempotent consumer in the route instead?

Comment: When using the idempotentConsumer are you using a particular IdempotentRepository or are you relying on the default (in memory) repository? Also, you do not describe what issue you're trying to fix? Are duplicates not being flagged (as would be the case if using the default repository)? Or, is there some other eeason you want to use a readllock?

Comment: @DariusX. I have updated my question with the additional information requested. Both the idempotent consumer and the idempotent readlock are working correctly individually, I am asking if there is a way I can use both of these things together.

Comment: Trying to understand your intent. Is it that you want to move files that are genuine duplicates, but do not want the false impression of duplicates just because two different consumers, on different nodes, are reading them concurrently?

Comment: I wish to move files that are genuine duplicates to a specific folder, I have already implemented this using the idempotentConsumer within the route. I also want to have a readlock which will stop two different consumers trying to consume the same file. I do not mind if the idempotentRepository on the file consumer allows duplicates (two copies of the same file, not the same file twice) through as these will be caught by the idempotentConsumer in the route.

Comment: Got it. I believe Miloš's answer addresses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same idempotent repository keys for locking and consuming purposes then you won't be able to try processing the same file twice - idempotent consumer's check will happen after read lock's check so your file will be skipped before the consumer gets to check if it exists or not. Also, I think you may encounter issues with the consumer and read lock itself since the consumer may report your file as existing since the read lock will insert the row in the DB before the consumer does the check.

The fastest solution that I can think of is to use different keys for idempotent consumer and read lock - that way there won't be any conflict between them - and also make read lock remove the key on commit by setting `readLockRemoveOnCommit` to `true`. This way, the read lock will not allow concurrent processing of the file but will use idempotent consumer's key to check whether the file has been processed before or not.